# Initial springboot starter project setup - facing issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, setup-project

I am trying to make a simple spring web application using Spring boot starter package provided. I am able to display 'Hello World' into console, but when I am trying to open localhost:(port), it is showing me . I am using JRE 8. Tried using JDK8 but also gives me same error. Do we have to use JDK or JRE ?

> Whitelabel Error Page
>   This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>   Mon Jul 02 21:58:01 MDT 2018
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   No message available

I am trying to resolve this issue from  from last 2 days but I am stuck at this!.

Please find below images and code which I have in my system.

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tExx.jpg)

Spring Starter Project Application .java

```
package com.gami.mvc;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringStarterProjectApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringStarterProjectApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringStarterProjectApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Pom.Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.gami.mvc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springStarterProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>springStarterProject</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- This is a web application -->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tomcat embedded container -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, test for static content, bootstrap CSS -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Contoller. java

```
package com.gami.mvc;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

public class WelcomeController {

    // inject via application.properties
        @Value("${welcome.message:test}")
        private String message = "Hello World";

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
            model.put("message", this.message);
            return "welcome";

        }
}
```

Application.properties

```
server.port=8456

spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

welcome.message: Hello Gami
```

Error receiving when running the application

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EyML.jpg)

Please any help is really appreciate!

Thank you 
Hardik Gami 
[Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XJWm.jpg)

[Console msg after hitting to local host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/non6a.jpg)

[Java Build Path Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtL6h.jpg)

Java Build Path - Eclipse [Java Build Path of Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzkWk.jpg)

Comment: Oh yes, .jsp file is inside webapp/Web-INF/Jsp.. but it is present and its name is welcome.jsp.

I have tried opening sample spring boot webapplication in eclipse to run, but always shows me Error Message as mentioned above

Comment: Please check the error stacktrace in your IDE console to get exception details.

Comment: you do not @RestController annotation on your welcomecontroller.

Comment: @AmithKumar , I have updated the question with console image. I don't see any error exception. Also it prints out Hello world perfectly fine

Comment: You need to annotate your controller class with `@Controller` or `@RestController` (read their docs for more info) to let Spring discover them.

Comment: Hello sn42, I have added @Controller Annotation and after that it gives me compilerClassName: [null] and compiler: [null]  inspite of having JRE compiler. I have the image in question.  Link is -> 'Java Build Path Error

Comment: Have you tried using the JDK instead of the JRE? The compiler should only be available in the JDK.

Comment: which tool you are using? If Eclipse can you share screen shot of yourproject -> properties-> Java Build Path

Comment: sn42 - I have tried with JDK , it comes same error..

Comment: Shaunak Patel -  I have added the screenshot of Java Build Path. Yes, I am using Eclipse. I tried using STS it gave me the same error. 

Image is there in the question - Java Build Path - Eclipse Java Build Path of Project

Comment: Please check if you have maven dependencies in deployment assembly tab

Comment: How did you create the project? Using Spring Initializer?  https://start.spring.io/

Answer (score 1):

Spring will search for classes annotated with `@Controller` on the configured search path, without this annotation spring won't pick up your controller class.

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController { ... }
```

Comment: Hello Alien ->  I did add @Controller over WelcomeController.java class, and when I ran, it gave me an error that no Compiler found. When checking buildpath - I have JRE clicked. I have updated the question with the image too..

Webpage error when accesing localhost.
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Jul 02 22:44:03 MDT 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No Java compiler available for configuration options compilerClassName: [null] and compiler: [null]

Comment: refer this https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-web-jsp-no-java-compiler-available/

Comment: I am using mykyong spring boot Hello world example itself.  Just have changed package name, other than that - Syntax , html and css file are the same. When I add 
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
   <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
   <version>4.6.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

in the pom.xml, it should an Exclamatory mark at the bottom of the project and wont compile.

Answer (score 1):

Need to annotate your class with @RestController, or this will search for the welcome.jsp

Answer (score 1):

JRE will not have the Compiler. Use JDK, which will have development tools like javac, javap etc.